# How to promisify existing callbacks without async await

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, bluebird

I have some controllers where many callback functions are used instead of async await. I am using bluebird promise library to promisify. In callback function there are many mongoose methods like `find, findOneAndUpdate.` But there is no option to append Async in front of theses methods. Is there any way to handle this. Or I'm I doing this the wrong way?

```js
app.get('/acceptTeam/:TeamID', (req, res) => {
    TeamTerms.findOneAndUpdate({ TeamID: req.params.TeamID }, { status: 'ACCEPTED' }).then(() => ).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).send();
    });
  });
```

Comment: mongoose supoorts promises so you dont need bluebird or other libraries

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises)

Comment: mongoose support promises but they are relatively slower than bluebird